# Is this abusing the generic type system?

Tags: .net, generics, clr, language-design

Suppose we had a compiler that compiled into .Net where all the methods would be generic, on all their types (parameters, and locals), and you wouldn't specify the types when writing a method, but the constraints instead.

When compiled, a method could look like this for example:

```
interface IFoo<T> {
    T Foo();
}
interface IBar<TParam, TResult> {
    TResult Bar(TParam param);
}
public TResult FooBar<TItem, TParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(A item, B param)
    where TItem: IFoo<TIntermediate>
    where TIntermediate: IBar<TParam, TResult> {
        return item.Foo().Bar(param);
}
```

It would have a syntax meant for this and types would be inferred, e.g.

```
FooBar = (item [I], param [P]) [I: IFoo<X>, X: IBar<P, R>] => [R] {
    item.Foo().Bar(param)
}
```

Would a program where most methods are compiled like this (except ones where exact types can be inferred from usage) be *using* .Net's advanced generic type system or *abusing* it?

For example, would such a thing slow down the CLR because it's got too many jitted types, or would it 'just work', as efficiently as normal code?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the runtime would have to JIT compile more code using generics than if you had written it all out yourself?

Comment: @Gabe: I'm suggesting that if all my methods are compiled this way the runtime would have to keep track of each method's compiled version's types, meaning even if I only use one type (or compatible type) for each parameter it would have to keep track of more data. The question is whether this is an unreasonable strain on the type system.

Comment: This is done by the jitter.  Once it is compiled to machine code, there is no additional overhead.

Comment: One problem here are method overloads. One case where this is very annoying is with operator overloading.

Comment: I wouldn't do it unless necessary because Generic virtual methods have an order of magnitude overhead. A regular method and a generic method have a very tiny bit of performance difference (measured in ms for millions of invocations). They also aren't supported in open delegate call sites.

Answer (score 2):

There is a major problem with procedures that combine generic type constraints: there is no general way to typecast an object so that it can be passed to such a routine--a situation very different from routines without such type parameters.

If a routine expects e.g. an IFoo and I want to pass it some object which I believe to be an IFoo, I can cast the object to an IFoo and pass it to the routine.  If it's possible that the object might be an IFoo, the compiler will generate code which will assume the object is an IFoo and fail if it doesn't.

If a routine accepts a generic-type parameter, the passed-in object must be of a *compile-time* type which meets all the constraints.  If there's just one constraint and it's a particular base type or interface (e.g. IFoo), that's easy--cast it to the type implied by the constraint.  That compile-type type of the object after the typecast will satisfy the constraint, and if the run-time type of the object would satisfy the constraint, the cast will succeed.

Difficulties arise, however, if one wants to call a routine Wowzo whose parameter is constrained to implement multiple constraints, e.g. interface IFoo and base-class Wuzzle, but the objects one would want to pass to that routine don't share any common base type satisfying the constraints.  For example, suppose classes Wuzzle1, Wuzzle2, and Wuzzle3 all implement IFoo, and all inherit from Wuzzle, but Wuzzle doesn't implement IFoo.  I have an array of Wuzzle, the items in it are a mixture of Wuzzle1, Wuzzle2, and Wuzzle3.  If an array element happens to be a Wuzzle1, I can cast it to a Wuzzle1 and pass it to Wowzo.  If it happens to be a Wuzzle2, I can cast it to a Wuzzle2 and pass it to Wowzo.  Likewise with Wuzzle3.  Unfortunately, there's no nice "generic" way of passing the array elements to Wowzo, without having to deal explicitly with every possible type that might be in the list.

Comment: You raise a valid point with problems when using multiple generic constraints. In this hypothetical language you'd be able to say "variable x is of a type that's both a Wuzzle and an IFoo", with casting and the `as` operator working as you'd expect.

Comment: @configurator: I'm not familiar with the intricacies of .net's typing system, but would think that if it were easy in the .net type system to have fields or delegates of open constrained generic types, either vb.net or c# would allow such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: *Always* using generic constraints is a *needless* use of generics in the face of standard polymorphism, thus counting as an *abuse* of the feature in my book. I can't speak to the actual performance effect of the potentially large number of generic instantiations, but I wouldn't risk the hit if there's no benefit.

Long Answer:

For a proposed new language, you are free to have the syntax always look like that, but ideally, the compiler should attempt to make the actual compiled methods as non-generic as possible.  This improves the experience for the C#/VB/etc developer importing your libraries, as I do not believe generic constraints show well in Intellisense.  This also reduces the number of generic instantiations the runtime will have to make.  However, making that algorithm could prove quite difficult.  For example, I initially thought that your example method could be rewritten like so:

```
TResult FooBar<TParam, TResult>(IFoo<IBar<TParam, TResult>> item, TParam param)
{
    return item.Foo().Bar(param);
}
```

This is close, but not quite the same due to the lack of variance on `IFoo` and the possibility that `IBar` could be implemented by a struct, in which case variance still won't help.

On the other hand, an example of a bad time to emit a generic method is:

```
Write = (stream [S], data [D]) [S: Stream, D: byte()] => [] {
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
}
```

Here the straight-forward translation might yield:

```
public void Write<S, D>(S stream, D data) where S : Stream, D : byte[]
{ stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); }
```

where neither of the generic parameters are required because of standard polymorphism and you could emit this instead:

```
public void Write(Stream stream, byte[] data)
{ stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the one big problem would be method overloading. The CLR does not consider these methods to be different.

```
public void Method<T>(T arg){} where T:IFoo
public void Method<T>(T arg){} where T:IBaz
```

Admittedly, you can solve this in your language with the `modreq`/`modopt` parameter modifiers. However this means that either the information is lost to callers from most other .NET languages or simply can't be invoked by other languages.

Another pain point is performance of virtual methods degrades. Virtual generic dispatch is an order of magnitude slower than normal dispatch.

Finally, there really is no good way to solve the problem of constraint combinatorics, you'd have to emit a type to satisfy the type-system before jit time for instructions like `isinst` and `castclass` to work. So If you want to support `x as IFoo,IBar` you'd have to create an interface that is `<GeneratedInterface>_IFoo_IBaz:IFoo,IBaz`. Then x's actual type would have to add support the generated interface as .NET doesn't really have duck typing.

You may also come into reification pains `x as IFoo<T>,IBaz<T>` but T here is an impossible combination, (e.g. T in the first case is a struct, and T in the second case is class (x is actually a `Baz<T,U>` ). It might be very neat but very difficult to create such a language.

Answer (score 0):

If the resulting IL from such a programming language is verifiable, then it is not *abusing* the type system, because it is designed to run everything that is verifiable (and some of what is unverifiable).

My question would be - why would you want to do this? What's wrong with having staticly-typed method arguments that polymorphism deals with?

Comment: For one thing, you can't have multiple type constraints on the same variable. For example, I want an `IEquatable` that's also an `IComparable`. (I know, stupid example. Why would I even want that? But that doesn't mean it's not a valid requirement)